# CSV File's Contents Null in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a website that will display a large amount of data from a csv I have already written. I want to first upload the data to javascript to manipulate the data before displaying it. The CSV file is in the root website directory.

Here is the code for what I have now:

```
    var file = new File([""], "data.csv"
           , {type:"text/plain", lastModified: new Date().getTime()});
    const reader= new FileReader();
        
    reader.onload = function() {
        var contents = this.result
        console.log(file)
        console.log(contents)
    },false;
    reader.readAsText( file );
    }
```

Right now, the file's contents are empty even though my CSV has 500 lines of data. How can I read in the CSV file into javascript so that the data can be manipulated and displayed. The CSV file will be the same every time and will be from the website directory and not from the user uploading a file.

Comment: I guess a workaround to this would be writing a python script that turns the csv into a javascript file with the data in an array, but that seems like a really bad method to go about this

Comment: I think you're trying to read a local file. Normally, browser can't access local file because of security reason.

Comment: But don't browsers read local JS, img, css files? I'm confused why it wouldn't be able to read a local CSV file in the root web folder

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get a file in localhost by using XHR and it worked.
Maybe you can try this.

My index.html and test.csv are in the same folder.

```
<script>
    (() => {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "test.csv", true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
               console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
                
        };
        xhr.send();
    })();
</script>
```